# PHP Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in Lumen 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I got error when I try to run the following code
Error I am getting.
    `Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in Lumen 5.2.`

In My Route :

```
$app->post('oauth/access_token', function(Request $request) {

        $userverify=User::Where('username',$_POST['username'])->orWhere('email',$_POST['username'])->first();


        if($userverify){

             $request->input('username')=$userverify->email;                

        }  


        $json = array();
        try{
            $json = Authorizer::issueAccessToken();
        }catch (Exception $e){
            $json['error'] = 'invalid_credentials';
            $json['error_description'] = 'The user credentials were incorrect';
        }

        return response()->json($json);
    });
```

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you're assigning a value to a function's return statement right here:

```php
$request->input('username') = $userverify->email;
```

**$request->input()** is used **to only retrieve** the request values and not to set them.

If you still want to add some values to the request, then you might try using the following approach:

```php
// Add a value to the request
$request->request->add(['username' => $userverify->email]);

// Set a value in request
$request->request->set('username', $userverify->email);
```

Hope this helps.